# Sending keystrokes in Applescript via Automator in any application

Tags: applescript, macos-big-sur

I setup an Applescript quick action in Automator to leave a zoom meeting. No matter what application is in the forefront, I would like to check if zoom is running and if so, leave the meeting.

```
set appName to "Zoom.us"

if application appName is running then
    tell application id (id of application appName)
        activate
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "w" using command down
        keystroke tab
        keystroke return
    end tell
end if
```

It works! The problem is, if I'm in a zoom meeting and another app is in the forefront, I have to get permission from system preferences for that app to access system preferences. Like if I'm in Chrome, I have to allow Chrome to send keystrokes. Then, Chrome will always work.

I have to do this for every single possible app. Is there a way to get keystrokes in there without going thru this security stuff in Big Sur? I don't mind bringing up zoom to the forefront.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are issues at play here with using *global keyboard shortcuts* with **Automator** *workflows* saved as a *Service/Quick Action*.

- The *keyboard shortcut* assigned to the *Service/Quick Action* needs to not conflict with a default *keyboard shortcut* for whichever *application* is *frontmost* at the time it's pressed, otherwise there may be unwanted behavior.
- Every *application* that is *frontmost* when the *keyboard shortcut* is pressed on a *Service/Quick Action* using **UI Scripting** in the **Run AppleScript** *action* will need to have *accessibility privileges* granted for it (as you've already found this out and hence the question).

To workaround the *accessibility privileges* issue, here are three methods to achieve the goal that come to mind.

- The first, my preferred method for running **AppleScript** *scripts* with a *keyboard shortcut*, is to use a *third-party application* named [**FastScripts**](https://redsweater.com/fastscripts/), as it would not need to have every *application* that's *frontmost*, that hasn't yet been granted privileges, to be granted *accessibility privileges* to run the **AppleScript** *code* shown in your question. I'd imagine other similar type *third-party applications* that allowed assigning *keyboard shortcuts* and running a *script* would bypass the issue too, but have only tested the aforementioned.
- The second method, can be done with **Automator** as a *Service/Quick Action* using a **Run Shell Script** *action*, then assigned a *keyboard shortcut* and will work without having to give *accessibility privileges* to the *application* that is *frontmost* when the *keyboard shortcut* is pressed.
- The third method, can be done with **Automator** as a *Service/Quick Action* using a **Run AppleScript** *action* if changing a **zoom.us** default preference under **zoom.us** > **Preferences…** > **General** by unchecking **[] Ask me to confirm when I leave a meeting**, then when assigned a *keyboard shortcut* and will work without having to give *accessibility privileges* to the *application* that is *frontmost* when the *keyboard shortcut* is pressed.

All testing was done under **macOS Big Sur** using **zoom.us**, (Version: 5.4.7 (59780.1220)) with my **Language & Region** setting in **System Preferences** set to **US English** using the various methods presented.

---

**Method 1**

The first method using the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, show further below, and **FastScripts** with the *keyboard shortcut* **⌃⌥⌘W** assigned and works for me as coded.

In **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** I had the following added and checked:

- **FastScripts**
- **System Events**

Then with **zoom.us** running and several other *applications* which were *frontmost* when the *keyboard shortcut* was pressed I did not have to grant *accessibility privileges* to those other *applications*, **zoom.us** was brought to the front and closed.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
if application "zoom.us" is running then
    tell application "zoom.us" to activate
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        tell application process "zoom.us"
            keystroke "w" using command down
            delay 0.5
            key code 36
        end tell
end if
```

- <sub>Note for testing purposes, after testing **Method 1**, I quit **FastScripts** as it would have been triggered by the same *keyboard shortcut* which was assigned when testing the next two methods.</sub>
- <sub>FastScripts can be run as a free app, up to 10 keyboard shortcuts, or upgraded for $24.95 USD to unlock unlimited keyboard shortcuts. I have no affiliation with Red Sweater Software, LLC, other then as a user of FastScripts.</sub>

---

**Method 2**

The second method was tested using **Automator** and a *Service/Quick Action* with setting **Workflow receives [no input] in [any application]** using a **Run Shell Script** *action* with its default settings, and the following *example* **shell script** *code* is all that was used:

```bash
[[ -z $(pgrep -x 'zoom.us') ]] || pkill −x 'zoom.us'
```

In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** I assigned it the *keyboard shortcut*: **⌃⌥⌘W**

Then with **zoom.us** running and several other *applications* which were *frontmost* when the *keyboard shortcut* was pressed I did not have to grant *accessibility privileges* to those other *applications*, **zoom.us** was closed.

---

**Method 3**

The third method was tested using **Automator** and a *Service/Quick Action* with setting **Workflow receives [no input] in [any application]** using a **Run AppleScript** *action* replacing its default *code* with just the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "zoom.us" to quit
```

In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** I assigned it the *keyboard shortcut* **⌃⌥⌘W** after removing it from the *Service/Quick Action* created in **Method 2**.

Then with **zoom.us** running and several other *applications* which were *frontmost* when the *keyboard shortcut* was pressed I did not have to grant give *accessibility privileges* to those other *applications*, **zoom.us** was closed.

This of course works because the **[] Ask me to confirm when I leave a meeting** preference was unchecked in the preferences for **zoom.us**.

---

To recap, if you do not mind changing the mentioned default preference in **zoom.us**, then **Method 3** is probably the easiest and best way to resolve your issue as it allows for a graceful quit over **Method 2**, does not require any *third-party application*, and does not require any *accessibility privileges* be granted or **zoom.us** being *frontmost*, it just works.

I mentioned the other methods first as method one addresses the **UI Scripting** issue with **Automator** and a *Service/Quick Action*, and method two works with the default settings in **zoom.us**.